# Adding multiple letter codes from attribute columns in new column using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I am working in QGIS and trying to create a landcover vector for a project. I have multiple columns with different attributes. As shown below:

[image]

I was trying to create a three letter code in the `"ECcode"` column using a `CASE` statement but it was taking a long time and kind of painful to do. Is there an expression I can use that can simply add the values in the `"HCcode"`, `"MCCode"` and `"ECcode"` columns together so I could get values like `"HWDAG"`, `"HWDCO"` and so forth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the following expression to update the field `ECcode`:

```
  upper( "HCcode" || "MCCode " || "LCCcode" )
```

It will concatenate all the values in the three columns and change the case to uppercase. If you do not want the values to be uppercase, then remove the `upper()` expression.

Comment: For having a space or a different symbol in between use the `"HCcode" || '-' || "MCCode "` etc.

Comment: This is great! Thank you.